# What is the difference of target frameworks for unity3d?

Tags: unity, visual-studio

In `Visual Studio` in `properties` I can change `target framefork`.

[image]

I cannot find anywhere what means all of these magic titles.

What does it all mean (full, micro base, subset, web base)?

And...Can I use functionality of `.NET 4.6.1` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following Unity documentation at the moment this is the following supported .NET lib and their versions.

http://docs.unity3d.com/410/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoCompatibility.html

it has been mentioned several times that once Unity5 gets stable they will start adding more compatibility with newer versions.